# Parse.com relation query with selected keys

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, key

I'm trying to make a relational query with just some keys but its return all keys.
What am I doing wrong ?

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId) { (object:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            var relation: PFRelation = object!.relationForKey("MenuDetails")

            relation.query()!.selectKeys(["Receipe_Lvl1"])

            var testArray = NSMutableArray()

            relation.query()!.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects {
                            testArray.addObject(object)
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }

            }

        }


    }
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had never use Parse but i think that you should chain methods.

```
query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(objectId) { (object:PFObject?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {

            var relation: PFRelation = object!.relationForKey("MenuDetails")


            var testArray = NSMutableArray()

           relation.query()!.selectKeys(["Receipe_Lvl1"]).findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    if let objects = objects as? [PFObject] {
                        for object in objects {
                            testArray.addObject(object)
                        }
                    }
                } else {

                }

            }

        }


    }
```